# Прослушивание на голосовую команду в фоновом режиме на Андроид?

Tags: java, android

Стоит задача реализовать прослушку голосовых команд бесконечно долго (пока телефон работает, что логично). Если пользователь произносит команду Х, то происходит какое-то действие. Принципиально чтобы эта прослушка работала даже тогда, когда телефон лежит с выключенным экраном на столе. Каким-то образом Google Assistant это сделал со своим "Ок, Гугл".

Я уже попробовал стандартный SpeechRecognizer, но он не может слушать бесконечно. Пробовал создать цикл, чтобы прослушка запускалась заново, однако это уже получается костыль и есть небольшой промежуток времени, когда программа не слушает вообще. Пробовал также cmu sphinx - тоже не подошло. Наличие или отсутствие интернета для работы программы не принципиально. Есть ли готовые решения или как это реализовать самому?

Comment: Очень возможно, что для этих целей Google использует Daemon (доступ к нему имеют только сотрудники компании). Поэтому реально неубиваемый, существующий всё время работы телефона, скорее всего, сделать невозможно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Можно изменить некоторые параметры данного функционала, например:

1. `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` - Время, которое должно пройти после того, как слушатель прекратит слушать речь, чтобы считать ввод завершенным
2. `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS` - Минимальная длина высказывания, запись не прекратится до этого времени
3. `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` - 
   Время, которое должно пройти после того, как слушатель прекратит слышать речь, чтобы считать ввод, возможно, завершенным

Вот есть [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS) по данным методам. Так же можно в случае ошибки начинать прослушивание снова:

```
@Override
public void onError(int error) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(error);
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    speech.destroy();
    speech = null;
    StartListening();
}

private void StartListening() {
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

    //if setting.SpeechEnable
    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
}
```

Вот есть [вопрос_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430541/android-speechrecognizer-not-getting-started-again), [вопрос_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650072/android-speech-speech-recognition-repeated-calling-of-speechrecognizer-startlis) и [вопрос_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182893/can-i-keep-the-speech-recognizer-listening-indefinitely) по вашей тематике.

Comment: Да, я уже знаю про эти штуки. В документации написано: `The implementation of this API is likely to stream audio to remote servers to perform speech recognition. As such this API is not intended to be used for continuous recognition, which would consume a significant amount of battery and bandwidth.`. То есть данный функционал не предназначен для непрерывного прослушивания. Именно поэтому я и спросил здесь, если ли другие варианты прослушивания голосовых команд. Каким-то образом работает же "Ок, Гугл", значит технически это можно сделать

Comment: @goop51, а вы в основной активности слушаете команды?

Comment: Я еще никак не слушаю, я пока ищу решение. Насколько я знаю, вынести код в отдельный сервис или поток не проблема. Вы спросили потому что здесь есть что-то такое, чего я не знаю?

Comment: я думаю можно сделать и активность и сервис, и будет в сервисе слушать в фоне, вероятнее всего гугл так и поступил